# Should the getter return "or null" even when the value in the database is not nullable?

Tags: php, symfony, getter-setter, getter

I have a table that contains SMS verification message and i have a last sent column and number of tries column
So in the database they're not nullable but upon creating the entity in code, the values are initially null, so should i call setters before getters and make the getters return the correct value ( returns DateTime, returns int) or make the getter return or null even if the value in the database is not nullable ( this question is about best practice )

is it okay if it's

```php
getNumberOfTries(): ?int
```

or should it be strictly

```php
getNumberOfTries(): int
```

So should i say since the database value is not null then the getter should always return a value ? or is it okay that the getter returns null if i create a new entity without calling the setter for this value ?

Comment: This looks like LogicException when you try to use getter before the value was set via setter. So maybe throw the exception when the value is null?

Comment: PHP will already throw an exception "getNumberOfTries() should return int, null returned"
But my question is that is it okay to use getters that returns null before setters, or no, if the value is not nullable in the db then the getter shouldn't return null ?

Comment: No need to get fancy.  Just initialize your properties.  private numberOftries = 0; and move on.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a matter of opinion.

Heres the PHP DOC BLOCK that came out of my ORM. This is part of a larger autogenerated code ORM I wrote code from a MySQL dump using a php script. 
[PHP ORM Program](https://github.com/RichardTMiles/CarbonPHP/blob/master/programs/Rest.php)

```
/**
    * 
    *   $argv = [
    *       'select' => [
    *                          '*column name array*', 'etc..'
    *        ],
    *
    *       'where' => [
    *              'Column Name' => 'Value To Constrain',
    *              'Defaults to AND' => 'Nesting array switches to OR',
    *              [
    *                  'Column Name' => 'Value To Constrain',
    *                  'This array is OR'ed togeather' => 'Another sud array would `AND`'
    *                  [ etc... ]
    *              ]
    *        ],
    *
    *        'pagination' => [
    *              'limit' => (int) 90, // The maximum number of rows to return,
    *                       setting the limit explicitly to 1 will return a key pair array of only the
    *                       singular result. SETTING THE LIMIT TO NULL WILL ALLOW INFINITE RESULTS (NO LIMIT).
    *                       The limit defaults to 100 by design.
    *
    *              'order' => '*column name* [ASC|DESC]',  // i.e.  'username ASC' or 'username, email DESC'
    *
    *
    *         ],
    *
    *   ];
    *
    *
    * @param array &$return
    * @param string|null $primary
    * @param array $argv
    * @return bool
    */
 public static function Get(array &$return, string $primary = null, array $argv) : bool
{
... SEE LINK ...
}
```

With this use case the calling function or method actually gets two responses. The contents of the $return variable was passed by reference so if could now have different data in it and the success of the database to deliver a response was given by the bool return.

In your case, if I was constrained to make a method such as the one presented, I would not give the nullable option. I would assume the data was returned successfully from the DB and should it not be an INT I would go ahead and make it a 0. I would choose this option because it means less type checking in the calling functions. If null were to symbolize something else than I could see this giving reason to allow *: ?bool*. However, I hope with the code snippet above you can deduce a better alternative for the ORM.

I only personally use a possibly nullable response when I have three possible returns for a function. This happens almost never in web dev, but all the time in recursive programming.